# How do I redirect within an ErrorBoundary?

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I'm using ErrorBoundary in my React app and want to redirect to the main page when an error occurs - but my redirect is not working. Instead, the application stays on the same page.

In comparison, adding a button allows the user to switch pages on clicking it.

But I instead want to automatically take the user there when the error occurs.

Surely there must be an easy way to do this that I'm missing.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    this.setState({
      error: error,
      errorInfo: errorInfo
    })
    console.log(error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.errorInfo) {
      return (
        <div>
          {/* <Button href="/index.html">Go Home</Button> */}
          <Redirect to="/index.html" />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children; 
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

I've also tried returning a Route with no luck:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.errorInfo) {
    return (
      <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is index.html a route?

Comment: No, but I've also tried returning a Route with no luck. Updated my question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming you are also using `react-router-dom` inside your project.

Make sure that your ErrorBoundary component is inside the `BrowserRouter` wrapper in your `index.js` or `App.js` file. If so, you can simply connect your ErrorBoundary component to the react router by doing

```
export default withRouter(ErrorBoundary);
```

Make sure that it's imported correctly

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

If an error occurs you can then call:

```
this.props.history.push('/'); // will forward you to wherever you want
```

This will only change the url in the browser, depending on what else you have your ErrorBoundary doing you need to call

```
window.location.reload();
```

right after you pushed to the history. But this is only something you need to do when you configured your ErrorBoundary to overwrite your child props.

Comment: So then if I have that push and reload in my ErrorBoundary's ComponentDidCatch do I, or can I, leave out the render part of ErrorBoundary? When I have something there it flashes on the screen before routing to the other page. Would be nice to prevent that.

Comment: Would be interesting how this works with hooks and react router v6. Error boundaries cannot be used with hooks, so a react component is required.

Comment: Since react-router v6 doesn't provide a withRouter function anymore you can take a look at this: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it